# Postsharp get "Ambiguous assembly binding policies" error

Tags: unity-container, prism, postsharp, prism-6

When I add **Postsharp** (5.0.44) to one of my project, I get this error when compile it, after checking I see Postsharp has problem with **Unity (v4.0.30319**), updated Unity to version 5 and problem solved, but another problem is my other project using **Prism.Wpf (v6)** and this lib is not compatible with Unity v5, so I get deadlock now.
Actually I got same error ("Ambiguous assembly binding policies") before with **Prism.Core (v6)** but solved with v7.

Because I'm using 3 libs and they don't work together so I don't know where I should raise issue ticket, then I just ask if there is any workaround.

By the way, my projects use **.Net Framework 4.6.1**.

Here is full log

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unhandled exception (postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe release | .NET Framework 4.7.1): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Ambiguous assembly binding policies: Assembly 'system.runtime, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' redirects both to 'system.runtime, version=4.1.2.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'system.runtime, version=4.0.20.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyBindingPolicyManager.EvaluatePolicy(IAssemblyName assemblyName, Boolean evaluateSystemPolicies)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.^4+F3cylo(IAssemblyName _0, IAssemblyName _1, AssemblyBindingPolicyManager _2, BindingOptions _3, Boolean _4)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.^nQbUijLO(String _0, IAssemblyName _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindType(Type reflectionType, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.DeclarationCache.^pFnf8wEt()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.get_TypeIdentifier()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.DefinitionMatchesReference(INamedType definition, INamedType reference, BindingOptions options)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.^A9yFoe2uB3TC(ITypeSignature _0, BindingOptions _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.MatchesReference(ITypeSignature reference)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.CustomAttributeDeclarationCollection.Contains(IType type)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^SgrhoGlQ(AssemblyRefDeclaration _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^+GwnKh4ZYHu3()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation).
```

Comment: Could you please try PostSharp 5.1 preview? We did major changes to assembly binding which were not possible to deliver as a bug fix. I understand that using a preview version may not be an option for you, but we would appreciate to know whether the new version fixes your issue.

Comment: @DanielBalas Hi, it get "Error connecting to the pipe server. See previous warnings for details" error now, checking Warnings then I see these message: "Retrying to execute the pipe server" and "Connection unexpectedly closed by the server".

Comment: This is usually solvable by running the compilation under admin privileges and/or restarting your machine.

Comment: @DanielBalas I run Visual Studio with Admin right and still get that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use PostSharp with .NET 4.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847947/cannot-use-postsharp-with-net-4-6-2)